# Java - Command Execution in Runtime

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I tried out a simple program to execute Linux command at run time. But the following program gets compiled and runs without any error, but the text file is not getting created as intended.Is there anything wrong in this program?

```
import java.io.*;
class ExecuteJava
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            String historycmd = "cat ~/.bash_history >> Documents/history.txt";
            try
            {
                    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    Process proc = runtime.exec(historycmd);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println(e);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is attempting to write to a directory named `Documents` in the current directory the progam is running in. Does that directory exist?

Comment: @andy256 Yeah, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The append operator `>>` is meant to be interpreted as part of the command shell. Use

```
String[] historycmd = 
           { "bash", "-c", "cat ~/.bash_history >> Documents/history.txt"};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try accessing some of the functions [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) provides. I'd start with [exitValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29). Typically a `-1` indicates something went wrong while a `0` means nothing especially bad happened.

Also try [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) and [Error Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29), and read them fully. See if either has useful feedback for you.

Other than that, try what **andy256**  suggests in comments. Ensure the `Documents` directory exists in the executing directory of the program.